# ptpd2 not working on a peer-to-peer master-slave connection

Tags: linux, centos, timestamp, redhat, ptpd

I have a couple of x86 machines connected through a direct 10GbE connection. Interfaces are up and working (i.e. the machines can ping each other). Both machines run CentOS Linux.

I need to setup ptpd to synchronize the machines in order to get timestamps with a microsecond timing resolution.

I have:

- installed ptpd with yum
- edited the `/etc/ptpd2.conf` file (putting one machine as `masteronly` and the other as `slaveonly`)
- run the service through `service ptpd2 start`

The ptpd components communicate (verified either through through `tcpdump` and the ptp log files). Moreover, the `/var/log/ptpd2_kernelclock.drift` file shows the measured dritf.

However, `date` shows that times are not synchronized and a simple client-server test shows that timestamps are not synchronized.

Any idea what is wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution we've found has been to reinstall ptpd through `yum`. For some (very weird) reason, re-installing ptpd with the same configuration file solved the wrong behavior.